# incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT in render action

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, utf-8

> ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8
>   and ASCII-8BIT):   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27:in `new'

```
  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    if params[:post]
      @post = Post.new(post_params).dup
      if @post.valid?
        render :action => "confirm"
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    else
      @post = Post.new
      @document = Document.new
      @documents = @post.documents.all
      @document = @post.documents.build
    end
```

I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: which gem are you using for db??

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure `config.encoding = "utf-8"` is there in **application.rb** file.
- Make sure you are using `'mysql2' gem` instead `mysql gem`
- Putting `# encoding: utf-8` on top of rake file.
- Above `Rails.application.initialize!` line in **environment.rb** file, add following two lines:

  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8

  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

solution from here: http://rorguide.blogspot.in/2011/06/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii.html

If above solution not helped then I think you either copy/pasted a part of your Haml template into the file, or you're working with a non-Unicode/non-UTF-8 friendly editor.

If you can recreate that file from the scratch in a UTF-8 friendly editor. There are plenty for any platform and see whether this fixes your problem.

Sometimes you may get this error:

> incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

That typically happens because you are trying to concatenate two strings, and one contains characters that do not map to the character-set of the other string. There are characters in ISO-8859-1 that do not have equivalents in UTF-8, and vice-versa and how to handle string joining with those incompatibilities requires the programmer to step in.

Comment: @ShionYamaguchi : Sublime is popular editor. You can customize its setting as per your requirement too. You can set `UTF-8` or preferred as your default encoding  [check here](http://superuser.com/questions/581553/sublime-text-2-encoding-utf-8)

Comment: Tried all of these and still getting the error. I am using MongoDB not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I was upgrading my rails and spree and the error was actually coming from cache

Deleting the cache solved the problem for me

```
rm -rf tmp/cache
```