# rspec test failures with present to non-English symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, rspec, ascii

I'm comparing multiple files containing russian characters, and that's a result of getting. I replaced the symbols and the tests were properly

My environments: Rails 5.0.0.1 and ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

Files use utf-8 encoding.

`Failure/Error: Feror::AppGenerator.start args, { destination_root: spec_path }
    Encoding::CompatibilityError:
        incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8`

Comment: Probably this answer would help http://stackoverflow.com/a/29819539/7362128

Comment: @Slava.K I tested these recipes out there, but they did not help. With encoding all right because one of the tests of this file and repeat the same thing is done with the ascii characters.

Comment: You need to add some context here, like the code used to compare files. The default encoding for arbitrary files being read in can be different than the default source encoding.